# Some system calls close by an if statement but others open after a variable is declared

Tags: c, file-io, file-descriptor

What's the difference with my question?

```
 fd = shm_open(argv[1], O_RDWR_O);
 if (fd == -1)
      errExit("shm_open");
 ....
 ....
 if(close(fd) == -1)
      errExit("close");     /* 'fd' is no longer needed */
```

I don't understand how the close statement closes the file descriptor with just an if statement?

Why don't they close it before-hand and then do the if statment?

Do you understand my question? Else I can try to think of how to rephrase it or elaborate..

Comment: The return-value of `close` is (apparently) only used once: for that `if`-statement. Now there is no need for an extra variable to store that result in.

Comment: "The `close` statement" is a *function* that returns a value, and that value is checked. It's a normal instruction flow for all languages: the `if` cannot be "executed" before the function in its test is executed and *some* result is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write the second statement as;

```
int tmp; 

...

tmp = close(fd);
if(tmp == -1)
   errExit("close");
```

But since `tmp` serves no purpose after the check in the `if` (and a good compiler will indeed optimise it away), it has the same effect if you write it as the original code.

On the other hand, we can use assignments in if-statements, so:

```
 if ((fd = shm_open(argv[1], O_RDWR_O)) == -1)
      errExit("shm_open");
```

will also work.

The key here is that the first one does indeed store a value that we want to use later (if successfully opening the shared memory), so it's clearer to write it as two separate statements, rather than "hiding" it in the if-statement.

On the other hand, in the second case, we have no use for the result of `close`, so there's no purpose to writing an extra line and have an extra variable.

Comment: No *further* purpose. It is used as an error return check, but nothing else.

Comment: A better name than `tmp` would be `res` (a common name for this specific purpose) (or possibly `result`).

Comment: I choose the name `tmp` to show that it's a "temporary value, that we don't need again". But yes, if you actually want to keep a result, `res`, `result` or `status` would be a better name.